# right aligned button on custom DataGridViewButtonCell

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a custom `DataGridViewCell` that looks like this example

[image]

I started creating this cell. At first I inherit from a `DataGridViewButtonCell` and override the important methods.

```
    private class DataGridViewAllocationCell : DataGridViewButtonCell
    {
        public void Initialize() // Pseudo Constructor with some arguments
        {
            contextMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();
            // fill the contextMenu here
        }

        private ContextMenuStrip contextMenu;

        private const string BUTTON_TEXT = "...";

        private DataGridViewAllocationColumn ParentColumn { get { return OwningColumn as DataGridViewAllocationColumn; } }
        private int LabelWidth { get { return TextRenderer.MeasureText(FieldName, ParentColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Font).Width; } }

        protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates elementState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
        {
            base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, elementState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts.All & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentBackground & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);
            Rectangle displayRectangle = DataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(ParentColumn.Index, rowIndex, false);
            Rectangle cellRectangle = GetContentBounds(rowIndex);
            Rectangle labelRectangle = new Rectangle(displayRectangle.Location, new Size(LabelWidth, displayRectangle.Height));
            cellRectangle.Offset(displayRectangle.Location);
            base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellRectangle, rowIndex, elementState, value, BUTTON_TEXT, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics, FieldName, cellStyle.Font, labelRectangle, cellStyle.ForeColor);
        }

        protected override Rectangle GetContentBounds(Graphics graphics, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, int rowIndex)
        {
            Rectangle rectangle = base.GetContentBounds(graphics, cellStyle, rowIndex);
            return new Rectangle(rectangle.Left + LabelWidth, rectangle.Top, rectangle.Width - LabelWidth, rectangle.Height);
        }

        protected override void OnContentClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnContentClick(e);
            Rectangle contentRectangle = GetContentBounds(e.RowIndex);
            Rectangle displayRectangle = DataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false);
            Point location = new Point(displayRectangle.Left + contentRectangle.Left, displayRectangle.Top + contentRectangle.Bottom);
            contextMenu.Show(DataGridView, location);
        }
    }
```

When creating a column with these cells I get this grid

[image]

The important part is the second column. The button control is filling the rest of the cell.

Is there a way making the button as big as its text (default width) and align it on the right side?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you go with the approach of overriding `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` and inserting a button when it's focused rather than overriding `DataGridViewButtonCell` and drawing the text part.

Alas, what you did there is still valid and if you want the button to align differently you just have to specify different content bounds, i.e. instead of:

```
return new Rectangle(rectangle.Left + LabelWidth, rectangle.Top, rectangle.Width - LabelWidth, rectangle.Height);
```

You may put something like this, a right-aligned button 22 pixels wide:

```
return new Rectangle(rectangle.Width - 22, rectangle.Top, 22, rectangle.Height);
```

And your button will behave like a typical "..." button you'd expect. Anyways, therein lies the key to your problem.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Would you mind providing a full answer for the `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` solution? That would be really awesome. Currently I just know the `DataGridViewButtonCell` solution and this is really new to me

Comment: I just replaced the `22` with `rectangle.Height` because it returns me the value `21` I think this fits better